# Firebase Android Cloud Functions Change Timeout

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions library on Android and using getHttpsCallable to call a cloud function.

The problem is that the function needs 15-20 seconds to return the result back to the client, so the client throws an exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout.`

Is there any way to change the timeout?

Comment: The Firebase API does not support changing the timeout.  Suggest you file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent version of the SDK adds `setTimeout` and `withTimeout` methods that let you configure a custom timeout.

See the docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/HttpsCallableReference

Release Notes:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to change the timeout on the client.  The team is aware that this is a problem for some cases.  Until this becomes configurable, you have two options, your best option is write a regular HTTP function, and use your own HTTP client library that does allow configuring a timeout.

You can [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to add your voice.

Comment: OK I made a feature request and will try the first option until the feature is added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the article below is update on 25, Oct. So they probably added this feature by then. Not sure if it have been before.

As the [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) said, we can now describe both timeout and memory:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.myStorageFunction = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize((object) = > {
    // do some complicated things that take a lot of memory and time
  });
```

Or, editing it directly via the Google Cloud Platform Console:

1. In the Google Cloud Platform Console, select **Cloud Functions** from
   the left menu.
2. Select a function by clicking on its name in the functions list.
3. Click the **Edit** icon in the top menu.
4. Select a memory allocation from the drop-down menu labeled **Memory
   allocated**.
5. Click **More** to display the advanced options, and enter a number of
   seconds in the **Timeout** text box.
6. Click **Save** to update the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is in the Android client library. The OkHttp client time out after 10 seconds. And because of the cold start of the cloud function, it cloud take 15-20 seconds for the function to finish its execution.

Comment: Yeah, I thought timeout was my issue but it wasn't but I thought why not pasting the docs I found cause I thought it may be your issue. :)